# Create multiplot with map and scatter

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, r-sf

I am trying to create multiplot that contains a map (using `geom_sf`) and a graph next to each other.

I tried to use `GGpubr::ggarrange` and `cowplot::plot_grid` for this purpose. But I get this warning:

```
1: In as_grob.default(plot) :
  Cannot convert object of class tbl_dftbldata.frame into a grob.
```

And the result is not showing the map.

Does anyone know Any packages that can help me with this issue? A packages to use instead of `GGpubr` or `cowplot`?

Comment: Have you looked into the `{patchwork}` package?

Comment: Could you add data and reproducible code?

Comment: @RichPauloo Thank you! This is the answer I was looking for! can you post it as an answer?

Comment: @s__ Most of my data is confidential I cannot share them.

Comment: You can try to add fake data similar to yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### use [`{patchwork}`](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/)

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(maps)

# usa polygon in lamert equal area b/c it's pretty
usa <- st_as_sf(map("usa", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE)) |> 
  st_transform(st_crs("+proj=laea +lat_0=30 +lon_0=-95"))

# plot 1: geom_sf map of the us
p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = usa)

# plot 2: geom_line ggplot
p2 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_smooth()

# use pathwork to combine plots
p1 + p2
```

[image]